# Does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I tried to follow the tutorial but same error happen.

Error:

> Type 'FourthViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Here is my code:

```java
import UIKit

let characters = ["Jaja Bink", "Luke", "Han Solo", "Princess Leia"];

let weapons = ["LightSaber", "Pistol", "Keris"];

class FourthViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var doublePicker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView,
                    titleForRow row: Int,
                                forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if component == 0 {
            return characters[row]
        } else {
            return weapons[row]
        }

    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int? {
        if component == 0 {
            return characters.count
        } else {
            return weapons.count
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Replacing deprecated version of the method of protocol `UIPickerViewDataSource`, if you're using `Swift 3` could works for you.

**Deprecated Method of Protocol**

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

**Latest Method of Protocol in Swift 3**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

**Note:** Same true for other required protocol methods.
i.e

> Deprecated:

`func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int`

> Recent Version:

`func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int`

Answer (score 4):

Because your required delegate method is not correct.

Replace it with this:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if component == 0 {
        return characters.count
    } else {
        return weapons.count
    }
}
```

Your delegate method returns `Int?` which is not correct.

Comment: Oh God! i suddenly realised on my coding func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int i put extra Question mark '?' at the end of int. Now the issue resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Accept any answer if it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement it's function:

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int 
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

Comment: Oh God! i suddenly realised on my coding func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int i put extra Question mark '?' at the end of int. Now the issue resolved. Thanks!